# Android SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING

Tags: android

I want to call :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

But `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING` is only defined in API 11 according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING). What should I use if I want my application to be compatible with lower versions of the API?

Comment: try to add in manifest file

Comment: I cannot do that, because I have several views in the same activity and I want different behavior in different views. I know it's not exactly correct for an activity to have more views, but that was the request.